# maven selenium integration test

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I'm using selenium 2.8. I am getting a crazy error like this:

```
testPersistence(com.***.***.selenium.test.PersistenceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.032 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: ^@
        at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:107)
        at com.***.***.selenium.test.PersistenceTest.testPersistence(PersistenceTest.java:37)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:103)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:169)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ^@
        at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:112)
        at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:106)
        at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:275)
        at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.start(HttpCommandProcessor.java:237)
        at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:98)
        ... 28 more
```

my test class is very simple. its got a test like thislike this:

```
@Test
public void testPersistence() throws InterruptedException {
    DefaultSelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://localhost:8080");
    selenium.start();
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.open("/***/register.seam");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.type("registration:username", "jackman");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    selenium.type("registration:name", "Jack Daniels");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    selenium.type("registration:password", "123456789");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    selenium.click("registration:register");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("regexpi:Welcome"));
    selenium.stop();
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

thanks in advance

Comment: From the top of the error stack, it complains that it could not start selenium. Is your environment properly set up? Did you start the selenium server? Did you add the required dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

Your pom.xml is missing, so hard to judge what's going wrong.

However, in a simple test project, I only need in my pom.xml the following in the "dependencies" section (note, I'm using Selenium 2.22.0 instead of 2.8):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I invoke my tests using TestNG, but it should also work with JUnit.

My test case looks as follows. I stripped out everything related to proxy settings, so the example could probably even be simplified:

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, profile);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    Assert.assertEquals("Google", driver.getTitle().trim());
```

So one problem could be that you are using an outdated version of Selenium (2.8). Also the way you set up your DefaultSelenium looks wrong to me. Also, for Firefox you don't need the Selenium server running.

Another thing I don't understand is the wait for 30 seconds directly after starting selenium. What are you waiting for?

Comment: @Frank That's probably part of the problem. Looks like he copied some outdated example code. But if approaching something like Selenium, I would first try to use the latest stable release (oh, I need to update my post with 2.22.0).

Comment: That's right- I would also recommend using the last version (thx for telling me they updated to 2.22) but maybe there's a reason for her/him to use 2.8 so you might point out that you changed the version. Especially because (s)he had no pom at all... ;)

Answer (score 0):

[The Maven Cookbook answer](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mcookbook/reference/ch08s02.html) of Running a Selenium Test with Maven.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ozyman has pointed out it looks like you have not started the Selenium Server. The Selenium Server must be running in the background if you want to use Selenium RC to create your tests.

You can use the [Selenium Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/selenium-maven-plugin/) to launch the Selenium Server before executing integration tests by adding the the following plugin configuration to   ...  .

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>start-server</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <background>true</background>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Get the plugin to use the latest version of Selenium drivers -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
      <version>2.26.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

You can turn your unit test into an integration test simply by renaming it from PersistenceTest to ITPersistenceTest. The [Maven Failsafe Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) will run the integration tests if you add the following plugin configuration to   ...  .

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
     <id>run-integration-tests</id>
     <phase>integration-test</phase>
     <goals>
       <goal>integration-test</goal>
     </goals>
     <inherited>false</inherited>
   </execution>
 </executions>
```

On the site for the Selenium Maven Plugin there is [guidance](http://mojo.codehaus.org/selenium-maven-plugin/examples/using-with-surefire.html) of how to use the force the Maven Surefire Plugin to run as part of the integration-test phase of the build life cycle.

If you are going to be writing a lot of Selenium based unit tests you might find the S[elenium JUnit 4 Class Runner](http://selenium-junit4-runner.btmatthews.com/) useful in reducing the amount of boiler plate you need to add.